# solution of SDE: $dS_t=(\alpha S_t+f(t))dW_t$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

does someone know how to solve the following SDE

$$dS_t=(\alpha S_t+f(t))dW_t, S_0=s$$

where $f(t)$ is a deterministic function and $W_t$ is a standard brownian motion. Is there a explicit solution for this SDE? Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Note that the SDE $$dS_t = (\alpha \cdot S_t+f(t)) \, dW_t \qquad S_0 = s$$ is a linear SDE and therefore there is indeed an explicit formula for the solution of the SDE. One approach is the following:

1. Solve the homogeneous SDE $$dS_t = \alpha \cdot S_t \qquad X_0 = x$$ There are several possibilities to do so: Either you have some intuition how the solution might look like or you apply Itô's formula to $X_t := g(W_t)$ to obtain conditions on (the derivatives of) $g$ allowing you to determine $g$.
2. Solve the inhomogeneous SDE $$dS_t = (\alpha \cdot S_t+f(t)) \, dW_t$$ One approach is the so-called variation of constants: Let $S_t^0$ such that $\frac{1}{S_t^0}$ solves the homogeneoues SDE, $S_0^0 = 1$ (we solved this SDE in the first step, so there is an explicit formula). Now we apply Itô's formula to $$Z_t := S_t \cdot S_t^0$$ which works fine since we know $dS_t$, $dS_t^0$. Therefore, we can determine $Z_t$ and consequently also $S_t = \frac{Z_t}{S_t^0}$.

Literature: e.g. *René L. Schilling/Lothar Partzsch: Brownian Motion - An Introduction to Stochastic Processes*

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to check that
\begin{align*}
d\left(e^{-\frac{\alpha^2}{2}t - \alpha W_t } S_t  \right) = e^{-\frac{\alpha^2}{2}t - \alpha W_t } f(t) dW_t.
\end{align*}
Then, $S_t$ can be solved subsequently.

Comment: What is a motivation behind considering the discounting factor?

Comment: It is the integration factor, and is motivated by the usual treatment for mean-reverting processes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is the integrating factor same as in first order ordinary differential equation?

Comment: Yes. Very similar idea.